# Django form rendering with initial data

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a question model and answer models depending whether the question is multiple choice or text input.

In my views I am trying to render the form with initial data. The initial data will get the user answer if it has already been answered and it works fine but when a question appears whose answer has not been given by the user then the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception is thrown and it says

"UserTextAnswer has no my_answer" which is given in templates.

My Models:

```
Question_Types_Choices = (
    ('multiple_choice', ('multiple_choice')),
    ('text_input', ('text_input'))
)

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length = 250, choices =Question_Types_Choices)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , auto_now=False)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text[:10]

class FreeTextAnswer(models.Model):
    answers = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text[:10]


class UserTextAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)  
    my_answer = models.ForeignKey(FreeTextAnswer)
    my_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.my_answer.text[:10]
```

In my views:

```
def single(request,id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():


        queryset = Question.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
        instance = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)


        try:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer.objects.get(user=request.user, question=instance)
        except UserTextAnswer.DoesNotExist:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer()
        except UserTextAnswer.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer.objects.filter(user=request.user, question=instance)[0]
        except:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer()



        try:
            free_text_answer = FreeTextAnswer.objects.get(answers_id=instance.id)
        except FreeTextAnswer.DoesNotExist:
            free_text_answer = FreeTextAnswer()
        except FreeTextAnswer.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            free_text_answer = FreeTextAnswer.objects.filter(answers_id=instance.id)[0]
        except:
            free_text_answer = FreeTextAnswer()


        initial_dict = {
            "my_answer": user_text_answer
            }

        form2 = UserTextFreeForm(request.POST or None, initial = initial_dict)
        form = UserResponseForm(request.POST or None)


        if request.method == 'POST':


            if form2.is_valid():
                "process the form"
```

In my templates I am rendering it like this,

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url "question_single" id=instance.id%}' > {% csrf_token %}

<h1>{{ instance.text }}</h1>

<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='{{ instance.id }}' />

<h3>Your answer</h3>

   {{ form2.my_answer.errors }}
    {{ form2.my_answer }}




<input type='submit' value='Save and continue' />

</form>
```

The initial dictionary for the question whose answer has not been should be empty but i have tried to check the length it is always returned one. I have also tried to catch the user_text_answer.DoesNotExist exception but not working.

How should i control my initial dictionary so that when a question has no answer it loads normally without the data and if it has the answer linked with it then it should display the data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get` with validation of `DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned` you could just use `filter` with [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```
user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer.objects.filter(user=request.user, question=instance).first()

initial_dict = {}
if user_text_answer:
    initial_dict["my_answer"] = user_text_answer
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out why the initial dictionary was returning a value of one even when it had to be empty. I resolved it by doing the following:

```
try:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer.objects.get(user=request.user, question=instance)
            initial_dict = {
            "my_answer": user_text_answer
            }
        except UserTextAnswer.DoesNotExist:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer()
            initial_dict = {

            }
        except UserTextAnswer.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer.objects.filter(user=request.user, question=instance)[0]
            initial_dict = {
            "my_answer": user_text_answer
            }
        except:
            user_text_answer = UserTextAnswer()
            initial_dict = {

            }
```

It should be initialised according to the situation inside the try and except block and not after that.